# Proguard Error returning error code 1 with UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to build application with Proguard and using following code for proguard -

```
-dontwarn android.support.** 
-dontwarn org.kobjects.**
-dontwarn org.ksoap2.**
-dontwarn org.kxml2.**
-dontwarn org.xmlpull.**

-optimizationpasses 25
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic

-keep public class * extends android.app
#-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
#-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
#-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-assumenosideeffects class java.lang.System {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** e(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** w(...);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
 }
```

And while building I am getting following error -

```
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject] Note: there were 4 duplicate class definitions.
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject] java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitAnyClass(SimplifiedVisitor.java:47)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitLibraryClass(SimplifiedVisitor.java:59)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.classfile.LibraryClass.accept(LibraryClass.java:301)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.subclassesAccept(ProgramClass.java:433)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.optimize.peephole.VerticalClassMerger.visitProgramClass(VerticalClassMerger.java:83)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:116)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:565)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:306)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:115)
[2014-08-26 15:45:45 - MyProject]   at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Currently I am using appcompat_v7 as library which it builds automatically while creating Master flow Activity.

Following libraries are used in appcompat_v7

- android-support-v4.jar
- android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies are contributed to dependent project

[image: Build Path of appcompat_v7 project]

Please help me out. Thanks in advance